# Screenshot taken from client cannot be used by fromstring to show them on pygame

Tags: python, pygame, zlib

I'm trying to take a screenshot from client and show it on my python screen, so I'm using the `pygame.image` function. However, it doesn't let me use `fromstring` and shows it as a warning... and then it doesn't work.

Code:

```
pixels = decompress(pixels)
scrn_img = pygame.image.fromstring(pixels, (950, 500), 'RGB')
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Which warning does it show?

Comment: its warns that its bytes and not string type

Comment: Please show the complete and exact error message with traceback.

Answer (score 0):

do:

```
pygame.image.load()
```

but if you wanna choose the width and length do:

```
pygame.scale.transform(pygame.image.load("picture_name.png"), (width, height))
```